# counting comparisions in mergesort

Tags: python, sorting, merge

I made mergesort by Python and it is working properly.And I need to count comparisions when this merge sort is running. I declare global variable 'merge_compare_count' because this is recursive function. And I use random numbers for elements of list A.

But the problem is whenever I run this code, I got always same merge_compare_count. I don't know why....

For example, when A got 5000 randomly different elements  but merge_compare_count always return same with 123616.

Any help will appreciate!!

Comment: Why do you think that's a problem?

Comment: Because listA got randomly different numbers of element but always same result is strange... I think....

Comment: Not strange at all. Also, please indent correctly and correct your "500" to "5000".

Comment: But I made another sort like quicksort and heapsort, those return each different count numbers even same length of A. That's why I thought this is strange or something's wrong....

Answer (score 2):

That's not a problem. The way it's written, your code simply has a deterministic number of those steps, depending only on the size, not the values. You can even compute them like this:

```
>>> def f(n):
        return 0 if n < 2 else f(n/2) + f(n-n/2) + 2*n

>>> f(5000)
123616
```

Comment: or *just* over 2 x n x log2(n), which is entirely expected for a O(NlogN) algorithm.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, especially for a Θ(n log n) one. It's actually almost exactly 2n⋅log2(n), not surprisingly. For powers of 2, it's exactly that.